# Fast copy of dict descendant

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, copy

As noted in ([Fast way to copy dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861498/fast-way-to-copy-dictionary-in-python)), `dict.copy()` is much faster than `copy.copy()`. I have a class that is a descendant of dict with a little extra metadata:

```
class DictWithTimestamp(dict):
    def __init__(self, timestamp):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
```

If I just do `DictWithTimestamp(1234).copy()` then I get a dictionary without a timestamp. Is there a way to preserve the speed of `dict.copy()` and keep my metadata?

Comment: just add copy function to your dict calling the dict.copy() and then copying your metadata manually.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do that? If I just called dict.copy() in `__copy__` I would get dict, and you can't set arbitrary attributes (like timestamp) on a dict

Comment: actually, by the looks of it from the code sample you provided it you may want to re-consider how you subclass from dict, as in you current example you just changed the `__init__` to accept timestamp only instead of behaving like an ordinary dict. there are some good SO answers covering that exact topic but it's much more complex that what you currently have (wrapper, ABC...)

Comment: Is there a reason that `timestamp` needs to be an attribute of the dictionary itself? Why not `DictWithTimestamp = namedtuple('DictWithTimestamp', 'timestamp data')`? I think the composition is warranted: in some sense, your approach involves inheriting a container and giving it a property (timestamp) that doesn't have much to do with being a container.

Comment: why not just add it to the dict and do a lookup to get the timestamp, `self["timestamp"] = timestamp`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I thought about that, but many users of this class iterate over the keys and values and expect certain data there, and having that extra timestamp in the dict itself would mess that up.

Comment: @jme That's not a bad idea, I might do that, although it would involve a big refactoring

Answer (score 0):

At first i thought about `__copy__` overriding but this way you will not use built-in dict copy method. So, jump to **update**!

You can define `__copy__` method for your `DictWithTimestamp` class in which you can copy additional class data. From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can
>   define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`. The former is
>   called to implement the shallow copy operation; no additional
>   arguments are passed. The latter is called to implement the deep copy
>   operation; it is passed one argument, the memo dictionary. If the
>   `__deepcopy__()` implementation needs to make a deep copy of a component, it should call the deepcopy() function with the component
>   as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.

**update:** you can do it with `collections.MutableMapping` subclass (read more about it here: [How to "perfectly" override a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/python-how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict)):

```
class DictWithTimestamp(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, timestamp=None):
        self.store = dict()
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.store[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.store[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.store[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.store)

    def setstore(self, store):
        self.store = store

    def copy(self):
        copy = self.__class__(self.timestamp)
        copy.setstore(self.store.copy())
        return copy
```

Test:

```
>>> d = DictWithTimestamp(1234)
>>> d['i'] = 1
>>> d.timestamp
1234
>>> d1 = d.copy()
>>> d1.items()
[('i', 1)]
>>> d1.timestamp
1234
```

Comment: Unfortunately subclassing `MutableMapping` hurts the performance of everything else. For example, using `%timeit` it seems that getting an element with [] is 6x slower than a dict and setting an element with foo[1]=2 is 5x slower. For a direct subclass (as in the question) setting an element is as fast as a regular dict, and getting an element is only about 2.5x slower