# Python list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have little experience in Python, more in C. I am used to arrays of arrays, and that would be simple for me to do what I want, but this is not.

So I have a dictionary, which also has a list inside:

```
lightstate = {"on" : False, "bri": 0, "xy": [0.0, 0.0], "ct": 153}
```

I want to make a few copies of it, **which I can address with the value of a variable.**

In C, it would be arrayname[**varname**][0], so I would get lightstate 1, "on". Here, in python, I am not sure. The "xy" list also throws me off. To note, I am modifying existing code, so I can't just scrap it all.

So how can I do this?

Comment: use "copy" to create shallow or deep copies.

Comment: @MukulSharma that doesn't help me too much. I could manually create the copies, it's being able to address them with a variable that I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried with the accessing them lightstate["xy"][0], it will work

Comment: Yes, that works. It gives the first value of "xy". Now I want to make a multidimensional array of this dictionary, so I can access it like I would in C. So lightstate[1]["xy"], lightstate[2]["xy], and so on, where 1 and 2 are values of the variable "count"

Comment: You mean you want a list of these dictionaries ? I changed my code in this way.

Comment: @Vinzee is thats what I need, then yes :)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can copy a `dict` object like this:

```
new_dict = dict(lightstate)
```

So if you want to make a few copies of it and store them in a `list` for example, you can write:

```
nb_copies = 10  # Your number of copies
new_dicts = [dict(lightstate) for i in range(nb_copies)]
```

You can access the values of the dictionaries by doing so:

```
# lightstate = {"on" : False, "bri": 0, "xy": [0.0, 0.0], "ct": 153}
on_value = new_dicts[0]["on"]
bri_value = new_dicts[0]["bri"]
xy_value = new_dicts[0]["xy"]  # It is a list: [0.0, 0.0]
ct_value = new_dicts[0]["ct"]
```

Comment: So how would I get the value? newdicts[0]["on"] ? What about for "xy" which is a list? newdicts[0]["xy"][0]?

Comment: @Vinzee shallow or deep copies can be created with "copy". I think dict(lightstate) might be slower since in case of list(something) we iterator over the list to return a list_object

Comment: @MukulSharma I thought `copy` was making a shallow copy but not a deep copy. But I may be mistaking

Comment: @Vinzee copy.copy() returns a shallow copy and copy.deep_copy() returns a deep copy

Comment: @MukulSharma You mean `copy.deepcopy()` without the underscore ?
I didn't know about it

Comment: @Vinzee yes, i mistakenly put underscore there

Comment: @Vinzee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861498/fast-way-to-copy-dictionary-in-python looks like its pretty much the same

Comment: That seems to be what I need. But the last thing is, can the new_dicts[0]["xy"] still be accessed as a list. As in x value = new_dicts[0]["xy"][0] (part of the code accesses lightshow["xy"][0] for the first value of that list.

Comment: Yes, sure ! `x_value = new_dicts[0]["xy"][0]` and  `y_value = new_dicts[0]["xy"][1]`